# Unable to build CSS while using tailwind

Tags: tailwind-css, webpack.config.js

The Config file :

```
/\*\* @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
content:["./TAILWIND/dist/*.hrtml"],
theme: {
extend:{},
},
plugins:[],
}
```

The Code i ran in terminal :

```
npx tailwindcss -i ./TAILWIND/src/input.css -o ./TAILWIND/dist/Task1.css --watch
```

THE Screenshots
[The problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4vrd.jpg)
[My Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtJi7.jpg)

[Config File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1dLZ.jpg)

Other things are good to goo,I checked the official documentation

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I see the config has a typo which seems the problem.

> content:["./TAILWIND/dist/*.hrtml"],

Try removing the `r` letter.

Comment: Unbelievable , my hole life is a lie now . thanks dude

Comment: Don't forget to make the answer as the solution.

Comment: @wpplumber This even shouldn't be an answer but a comment and a close-vote as the question is non-reproducible due to a typo

Comment: Is there a ref link to check that in the SO rules to confirm the info?

Comment: [Should we answer or comment on a typo question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174389/should-we-answer-or-comment-on-a-typo-question)

Comment: "but is a legitimate thing to do."

 I should take care of that next time, thank you